# Open files in editor from FileSystem API(HTML5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-filesystem

i am using FileSystem API in HTML5 to read files loaded from local fileSystem using input tag and make a duplicate copy of the file in the FileSystem.
I am trying to open this copy into the respective editors but no success till now.
using toURL() method, file is opened in browser except microsoft files( .docx, .xlsx, etc). This will let me fetch file from server and open in editor without storing the file on client machine and make changes to the one loaded in the fileSystem API inside browser.

Is there any way to open the file from the fileSystem into local editors including that of Microsoft office one's.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the toURL() method to generate a URL for the file stored in FileSystem?  Try using that method and present your users with the synthetic URL (which should start with something like "filesystem:chrome-extension://") for them to click and have the source file pushed to them from local storage.

Comment: i tried it using the window.open method. It simply opens the file in the web browser window. My problem is, i want to interact with the local editors so that the files can be opened in 'edit' mode and not read-only. And then, somehow, capture the changes and save the file in the browser filesystem and send it to server.

Comment: OK, now I understand your request a bit better. Unfortunately, you cannot use the FileSystem API as a virtual hard drive in that way. When an application (such as Word, Excel, or other local app) saves a file, it must save it to the local disk or network share; the browser is not available for that.  I sounds neat, but it's not doable.

Comment: thanks @PhilNicholas. if i could have the FileSystem API implemented in IE10 (i am still working on that), then i can make use of ActiveXObject to do it, but then it will be specific to a browser which i don't want :(.

Comment: Hey, any news on this? Have you managed to open the file in local editor app?